# Replacing GRUB2 with Windows boot loader

Tags: windows-7, grub2

I'm trying to replace GRUB2 with Windows' standard boot loader (bootmgr?), but I can't get it to work.

My Windows 7 install is in a single NTFS partition, which is marked as active (boot flag is set).

First, I tried the automatic repair with the install disk, but it didn't detect any problems. Then I ran `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`, but all I got was a black screen at boot with a blinking cursor.

After that I created a boot partition for GRUB2, I figured, at least I can use it to chainload, but it give me a "disk reading error". If I used GRUB's ntldr loader, than I got error `0xc0000225` (some sort of BCD error). I tried to rebuild the BCD from the rescue environment, and it was successful, but the error didn't go away.

---

**Update**: I've tried to rebuild the BCD, but nothing changed...

---

**Update 2**: I reinstalled my system, as I found no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix [three items](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392):

- MBR
- Boot sector
- Boot Configuration Data store (BCD)

Try option 2 from [this page](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Recovering+the+Windows+Bootloader+from+the+DVD):

```
rem fix MBR
bootrec.exe /fixmbr

rem fix boot sector
bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force

rem fix BCD
attrib -h -s C:\boot\BCD
del C:\boot\BCD
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

As mentioned there, replace `C:` with your actual boot drive letter if necessary.

Comment: Same thing, black screen with blinking cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try to mark hidden Windows system partition as active, not the one with Program Files folder.